Extract doi from a text string
I have a large list with bibliometric information including the doi like this example:
stringdata = {{"name surname, 2207, journal name, vol5, p1233, doi 10.1016/j.enpol.2125.13.027"}, {"name surname, 2007, journal name, vol20, p33, doi [doi 10.1167/0020886984272851, 10.1167/0020886984272851]"}};
Note that the second row contains 2 dois (their are often but not always identical) Now I want to extract the doi for each row by using StringCaseslike this:
doiextr1 = StringCases[stringdata[[1]], Shortest[ "10." ~~ doiprefix__ ~~ "/"] ~~ doisuffix___ ~~ WordBoundary :> StringInsert[doiprefix, "10.", 1] <> "/" <> doisuffix]
which yields:
{{"10.1016/j.enpol.2125.13.027"}}
for the first row
and
doiextr2 = StringCases[stringdata[[2]], Shortest[ "10." ~~ doiprefix__ ~~ "/"] ~~ doisuffix___ ~~ ", " :> StringInsert[doiprefix, "10.", 1] <> "/" <> doisuffix]
which yields
{{"10.1167/0020886984272851"}}
for the second row.
My question is: I am looking for a code that can extract both rows. In the case of the second row just the first doi. Ist there a way to combine WordBoundaryand ", "in StringCases??
many thx

Flatten[StringCases[#, 
    "10." ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ "/" ~~ (WordCharacter | "." ) ..], 
   1] & /@ stringdata

or if you want the first only:
First@Flatten[
StringCases[#, 
 "10." ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ "/" ~~ (WordCharacter | "." ) ..], 
1] & /@ stringdata


It looks like your data is very structured, so you can take advantage of that.
tabledata = StringSplit[Flatten[stringdata], RegularExpression[" *, *"], 6]
(* 
  {{"name surname", "2207", "journal name", "vol5", "p1233", "doi 10.1016/j.enpol.2125.13.027"}, 
   {"name surname", "2007", "journal name", "vol20", "p33", "doi [doi 10.1167/0020886984272851, 10.1167/0020886984272851]"}} 
*)

You could even make a Dataset out of this. Now it's easier to clean the doi data, because it's now separated as the last column.
MapAt[StringCases[RegularExpression["[^ ,]+/[^ ,]+"]], tabledata, {All, -1}]
(*
  {{"name surname", "2207", "journal name", "vol5", "p1233", {"10.1016/j.enpol.2125.13.027"}}, 
   {"name surname", "2007", "journal name", "vol20", "p33", {"10.1167/0020886984272851", "10.1167/0020886984272851]"}}}
*)

Of course, you can extract that column at any point if you just want the doi data separated from everything else.

thats really nice way to solve this but the data is not always structured like stringdata...

You may define a StringExpression like:
se=StringExpression["doi ", __];

that can be used inside StringCases to extracts doi... from one string:
 StringCases[se]@stringdata[[1]]

To apply it to all strings, we need Map:
Map[StringCases[se], stringdata, {2}] // Flatten

{"doi 10.1016/j.enpol.2125.13.027", "doi [doi \10.1167/0020886984272851, 10.1167/0020886984272851]"}


thx but that does not yield the desired output. see my question above.
